# Vue.js Binding Dynamic Models

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to create a series of select tags from an array of dynamic properties.

Refering to the documentation on [Dynamic Select Options](http://vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#Dynamic_Select_Options)

However, I don't know the model name before i get the data, so I need to
create the v-model binding with a dynamic value.

Any ideas ?

Code on [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0r5a26k5/2/)

### HTML

```
<div id="selectApp">

<div v-repeat="dynamicSelects">
    
    {{key}}

    <!--THIS WORKS: <select v-model="setReps1" options="setReps1"></select> -->
    <select v-model="{{key}}" options="{{key}}"></select>

</div>  


<pre>{{$data|json}}</pre>
```

#### JS

```
new Vue({

    el: document.querySelector("#selectApp"),

    data: {

        dynamicSelects: [
            {key: "setReps1"}
        ],

        setReps1: [
          
            { text: '0', value: '0' },
            { text: '1', value: '1' }
        
        ]

    }
});
```

*update fiddler link *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i figured out a way to do this, creating a select component.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/winthers/pen/vOqgpr?editors=101)

```
<script id="sselect-template" type="x-template">
  <select v-model="data.selected" options="data.items"></select>
</script>

<div id="app">
   <div v-repeat="lists">
       <sselect data="{{lists[$index]}}"></sselect> 
   </div>
</div>
```